# how to provide animation in 3D model in a pdf using itextsharp?

Tags: javascript, pdf, animation, 3d, itext

I am using the itextSharp library to generate a pdf that contains a 3D model. I want to provide some animation in that 3D model. Is there any way to do this with itextSharp or javascript? An example code would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't tell me to use tetra4D or Prostep. I want to achieve it through programming in itextSharp.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:**

You can't.

**Long answer:**

If the U3D model has animations already defined, you can use iText (or any decent PDF library) to add some JavaScript to the 3D Annotation Widget that will trigger the animation to play, go to a specific step, rewind, loop, etc.

If you want to programmatically add animations to the model that can later be triggered, you'll need to use a U3D library and learn ***a lot*** of very complicated math... or use a 3D authoring tool like (the products that must not be named but are referenced above in a comment).

Comment: It looks like (www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) in Table 300 – Entries in a 3D stream dictionary and Table 301 – Entries in a 3D animation style dictionary both together can define or add new animation. I am a noobie so please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: 1) I don't know of any good U3D libraries that will help you with creating animations. Creating animations is generally done visually in an application and then output to U3D. 2) Tables 300, 301, and 302 refer to animation *styles*. Those dictionary entries tell the viewer *how* to play animations that are defined *in* the model.